# Servlet won't redirect to receipt page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

So I am stuck at the point where the user clicks a submit button and the page should go to a receipt page and display there information.

Am I blind or should this work?

All of the other redirects work just fine using the method I am using but for some reason it wont go to the receipt page.

### Servlet

```
package edu.witc.Assignment03.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Phone;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.States;


@WebServlet(description = "servlet to get act as controller between form and models", urlPatterns = { "/customerServlet","/addCustomer","/addPet" })
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomerServlet() {
        super();
    }


    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        Phone phone = new Phone();
        States state = new States();


        Collection<Phone> phones = phone.getPhoneCollection();
        Collection<States> states = state.getStateCollection();

            session.setAttribute("phones", phones);
            session.setAttribute("states", states);

        //}

    }







    private List<edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();



 private void addCustomer(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
           throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/customerManagement.jsp";
    processRequest(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }

 private void addPet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
         throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/pets.jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
  }




    private Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            if (customer.getCustomerId() == customerId) {
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    private void makeCustomerReceipt(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String url = "/receipt.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }



    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if("addCustomer".equals(action)) { 
            addCustomer(response, request);
            }
        else if("addPet".equals(action)) { 
            addPet(response, request);
        }


    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            customer.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
            customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
            customer.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
            makeCustomerReceipt(request, response);

        }

    }
}
```

### CustomerManagement.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="customerServlet" method="post">

        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br>

        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br>
        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
        Phone Number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="phone"/><br>
        Phone Type:<br>
        <select name="thePhones" id="selectPhones">
            <option selected value="choose">
                Select a Phone
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.phones}" var="current"  >
                <option>${current.getPhoneName()}</option>              
            </c:forEach>        
        </select><br>
        Street Address:<br>
        <input type="text" name="streetAddress"/><br>
        Apartment Number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="apartmentNumber"/><br>
        City:<br>
        <input type="text" name="city"/><br>
        State:<br>
        <select name="states" id="states">
            <option selected value="Wisconsin">
                Select a State
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.states}" var="current"  >
                <option>${current.getStates()}</option>             
            </c:forEach>        
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make it do something when customer is `null` so you can see that customer is probably null.

Comment: Also make it do something when customerId can't be parsed to an integer instead of just ignoring the error.

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but keep in mind I am still learning.  How do I go about doing this.  I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot, add `response.getWriter().write("..."); return;` to the two possible problem places where you are doing nothing now:

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           response.getWriter().write("Error: Customer ID could not be parsed to a number");
           return; //to exit the function: we don't want to do anything more if we encounter this error
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            customer.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
            customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
            customer.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
            makeCustomerReceipt(request, response);
            return; //to exit the function: you should always do this after forward or redirect
        }
        else
        {
           response.getWriter().write("Error: customer is null");
           return; //to exit the function
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so both errors are thrown.  How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: The first one is because you are using `request.getParameter("id")` but your form has no input with `name='id'`: `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<%=id%>' />`

Comment: The second one is for the same reason. `getCustomer(customerId)` is going to return the value for customerId=0 every time, which is apparently null.

Comment: Also you've defined a list `customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();` but in your doPost you never fill that list.  So no matter what value `customerId` is, `getCustomer(customerId)` will always return `null` because your list is empty.

Comment: You've got a serious missing component here: Shouldn't your addCustomer write to a database and your getCustomer read from the database?

Comment: like i said befroe I am a beginner and not writing to or retrieving from a database yet.  Alls I want to do is take customer info and then output it to a receipt page.

Comment: Well then for now, at the beginning of your doPost add a few lines of `customers.add("Some name");` to fill your customers list so it won't be empty.

Comment: okay but that leads to another problem I do not no how to do the jstl for the inputs in the customer Form.  Do you know of a good way if all i want to do is set them to a variable so I can return them later in the receipt